# php - notices when sum values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I am looping through to sum up total sales by month for all countries (Add up total sales for Month 1 as January, Month 2 as February...)  The code below works but I'm getting notices that I would like to clean up.  I have tried isset, but I get the same notices.  Below is the original array, code, and results with notices.

Here's the array:

### $results

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Month"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "AU"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(7) "9095.70"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Month"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "113993.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Month"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "AU"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(7) "7393.65"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Month"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Country"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    string(9) "100279.43"
  }
```

### Code: This loop gets me the results I need but throws Notices that I don't want.

```
$newarr=array();
foreach($results as $value) {
    $Month = $value['MONTH'];
    $Total_Sales = $value['Total_Sales'];
    array_key_exists( $Month, $newarr ) ? $newarr[$Month]['MONTH'] = $Month : $newarr[$Month]['MONTH'] = 0;
    array_key_exists( $Month, $newarr ) ? $newarr[$Month]['Total_Sales']+=$Total_Sales : $newarr[$Month]['Total_Sales'] = 0;
}
```

### Result are right

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    float(123088.7)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["MONTH"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Total_Sales"]=>
    float(107673.08)
```

### Notices that I don't want.

Notice: Undefined index: Total_Sales in /var/www/html/analytics/views/sales_year_line_data.php on line 134

Notice: Undefined index: Total_Sales in /var/www/html/analytics/views/sales_year_line_data.php on line 134

### This is line 134 in my code

```
array_key_exists( $Month, $newarr ) ? $newarr[$Month]['Total_Sales']+=$Total_Sales : $newarr[$Month]['Total_Sales'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find this error happening because you are using: `MONTH` as a key name but should be `Month`. Also because you are using 2 ternary, you create an instance of the `$new` array then use the `+=` on a key that doesn't exist previous. `If/else` works to remove this error because you create `$new` in one go:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$results[]  =   array("Month"=>1,"Country"=>"AU","Total_Sales"=>9095.70);
$results[]  =   array("Month"=>1,"Country"=>"CA","Total_Sales"=>113993.00);
$results[]  =   array("Month"=>2,"Country"=>"AU","Total_Sales"=>7393.65);
$results[]  =   array("Month"=>2,"Country"=>"CA","Total_Sales"=>100279.43);

$new    =   array();

foreach($results as $value) {
        // Here is your issue. You have -> $value['MONTH']; Should be -> $value['Month'];
        $month          =   $value['Month'];
        $Total_Sales    =   $value['Total_Sales'];
        // Use one instance of array_key_exists() here to remove errors
        if(array_key_exists($month,$new)) {
                $new[$month]['Month']       =   $month;
                $new[$month]['Total_Sales'] +=  $Total_Sales;
            }
        else {
                $new[$month]['Month']       =   $month;
                $new[$month]['Total_Sales'] =   $Total_Sales;
            }
    }

print_r($new);
?>
```

Gives you *(with no errors)*:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 1
            [Total_Sales] => 123088.7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Month] => 2
            [Total_Sales] => 107673.08
        )
)
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.